# Lorem Ipsum in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, lorem-ipsum

For some reason I can't seem to figure out, the snippets I am trying to use from the "Placeholders" package aren't working. As an example, according to the tab trigger for the snippet from Placeholders, when I type "lorem5", I should get several paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum type, instead I get 5 words or Lorem Ipsum type!

Each of the Lorem Ipsum snippets from Placeholders uses "lorem" and a number from 1-5, each one increasing in length of text, but when I type lorem and whatever number corresponds to the set tab trigger, I just get that many words, not the snippet I have assigned to it. I can't seem to find where the overriding shortcut is coming from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I can combine the Emmet package and the Placeholder package to get different paragraphs of lorem. Example: `p*2>lorem50` will equal:

```
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, alias, dignissimos, aspernatur, quidem nihil architecto sequi vero explicabo est maiores atque laudantium similique omnis iusto corporis molestias eveniet blanditiis nam numquam fugiat animi quis necessitatibus perspiciatis magni doloremque aperiam culpa adipisci nisi deleniti dolores. Vitae rerum obcaecati quasi asperiores itaque.</p>
                        <p>Ipsum, aspernatur, soluta distinctio debitis quos ab necessitatibus saepe facilis voluptatibus perspiciatis molestias laudantium minus magni ea pariatur reprehenderit officia provident deserunt quasi dolor optio dolore inventore eos. Accusamus, obcaecati, quod reiciendis recusandae amet fugiat dolores magnam velit provident repellendus vel eum exercitationem quia cum nulla perferendis quibusdam? Alias, dolore!</p>
```

`50` is equal to the number of letters in the paragraph.

Edit: [Emmet has lorem built in as well](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/lorem-ipsum/)

Comment: The issue is that the tab triggers within the placeholder snippets aren't working as expected, but I appreciate the tip!